# Slowness in Vim's bracket-matching with the default PHP syntax

Tags: linux, vim, syntax-highlighting

I am experiencing a noticeable slowness in Vim's bracket-matching and -highlighting feature. When the cursor is placed over a parenthesis or bracket, there is a delay of about 300ms on the console's responsiveness. As stated, this only seems to occur when working with PHP files. I am running Vim 7.2 on Debian Squeeze with a .vimrc file:

```
  1 set autoindent
  2 set smarttab
  3 set ruler
  4 set expandtab
  5 set termencoding=utf-8
  6 set fileformat=unix
  7 set number
  8 set tabstop=4
  9 set encoding=utf-8
 10 set shiftwidth=4
 11 set noswapfile
 12 set backspace=indent,eol,start
 13 set shortmess=lrwxI
 14 set history=50
 15 set background=dark
 16
 17 let php_folding=2
 18 let php_asp_tags=0
 19
 20 colorscheme desert
```

Is there any way to alleviate this slowdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see this locally; the matching parens is instantly highlighted.  Try this:

```
:set filetype=txt
```

...and see if things improve.  If so, something in vim's PHP handling configuration may be a bit out of whack.  Do you see the same behaviour on very small PHP files?  I'm on 7.2 on ubuntu and not seeing what you're seeing.

Hope this helps!
-Paul

UPDATE:  thanks for updating your question to include your .vimrc - this leads to another thing for you to test.  Please see if this doesn't help the situation - change php_folding to 1 rather than 2.  2 folds all { } regions so this may be somehow interacting with the parens-matching logic and causing the delay.

Comment: Also you say "on the consoles responsiveness" - are you running vim  in a terminal emulator, or on a virtual console (ctrl-alt-F1 for example)?

Answer (score 8):

Type this to turn it off per-instance:

```
:NoMatchParen
```

(capitalization is important)

Add this to your ~/.vimrc to disable it before the module loads:

```
let loaded_matchparen = 1
```

You only need one.  With the first, you have to type it every time you open a PHP file, but you can turn it on again at any time.  With the second, it's always off, but you can't simply turn it on again.